# Which is considered better to pass information between Activities on Android project, send a model or only an id?

Tags: java, android

I have an android app and I have 3 screens that the user must fill some fields. Each screen have 7 fields to be filled. At the end of the process, I submit the information to the server using Retrofit with an API.

This is how I pass the information between Activities in my first project

```
// first activity
AutoDados autuacaoDados = new AutoDados(... a lot of parameters ...);

Intent intent1 = new Intent(AutoInf_Lista_Generica.this, AutoInf_Menu.class);
intent1.putExtra("PARAM_ENV_DADOS", autuacaoDados);
startActivity(intent1);

// second activity
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras == null) {
    return "";
}
AutoDados autuacaoDados = (AutoDados) extras.getSerializable("PARAM_ENV_DADOS");
```

I have another project that I use the following code to pass data between activities.

```
// first activity
Intent intent1 = new Intent(AutoInf_Lista_Generica.this, AutoInf_Menu.class);
intent1.putExtra("ID_AUTOS", myId);
startActivity(intent1);

// second activity
intent.getIntExtra("ID_AUTOS", 0);
// code that recover the data from a SQLite database based in the "ID_AUTOS"
```

These both ways I was able to recover data between activities, but which way is considered better and why is it better?
Another question, is there a better way to pass data between activities ?

If possible, talk about the pros and cons about each approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between the tow ways is that in the first method you are passing an Object to the second activity while in the second method you are passing a primitive type.
which is better ? each way has its own use case, there is no better way, it depends on your use case